# コマンドひとつで複数のvscodeを開いて、それぞれのvscodeでdocker-compose upや、npm run devのようにサーバをたてるコマンドを実行したい

Tags: vscode, docker-compose

### 背景

実務で開発をしていると、たくさんのプロジェクトを同時にvscodeで開いて、それぞれのプロジェクトでサーバをたてる（docker-compose upやnpm run devやrails sなど）事が結構多いと思います。
２コとかならいいんですが最近はマイクロサービスの流行もあって、開発時にたくさんのサーバーを同時にたてる事も多くなりました。

### 問題点

Macを再起動するとvscodeは全部とじてしまいますし、当然サーバーも全部終了していまいます。
現状は、全部GUIから各プロジェクトをvscodeで開いて、vscodeが５コくらい立ち上がるので、それぞれのターミナル上でdocker-compose upとか、npm run devとかを実行しています。

ただこれがあまりに大変なので、シェルスクリプトかなにかでうまいこと、一発で５コのプロジェクトをvscodeでひらいて、それぞれのvscode上でサーバーをたてられないかなーと考えています。

とりあえず、vscodeをコマンド上から立ち上げる手段は発見しました。

[ターミナルからVisual Studio Codeを起動する方法【公式の方法】](https://qiita.com/naru0504/items/c2ed8869ffbf7682cf5c)

> ```
> code <プロジェクトのpath>
> ```

しかし、コマンド一発で各vscode上でうまいことサーバーを立ち上げる方法がなかなか見つからず、苦戦しています。
なにかアイデア、解決策等あればご教示おねがいしたく存じます。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

VSCode はあくまでエディタです。確かにターミナルの機能も呼び出すことができますが、「VSCodeを自動で起動して、その中のターミナルで各サーバを立ち上げて…」に拘らなければ、シェルスクリプトの中で docker-compose や npm コマンド等を記述して起動すれば事足りそうです。

Comment: VSCode はあくまでエディタです、というのは確かにそのとおりだと思います。ですが、実際のところ各vscode上でサーバを立てたほうがわかりやすくて楽なんですよね。